# Chrome does not opening

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I've installed "chrome stable" from terminal, but when I click on the icon for open it, it automatically close rapidly. Something into installation went wrong? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed chrome with those lines

```
$ wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'


$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade


$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Are your running 64 bit?

Comment: Can you **[edit]** your question to include the output of `uname -a`, as well as the output in the Terminal (if any) of running the command `google-chrome-stable`? I believe `google-chrome-stable` is still the correct command to run the versions of Google Chrome installed through that repository (but if not, you can try just `google-chrome`), and by running it this way in your Terminal rather than from your graphical interface, you may see useful errors or warnings.

Comment: Linux giovanni 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux @EliahKagan

Answer (score 0):

I think , your OS it's not compatible for that chrome , i mean maybe that chrome is 32 bit and you was install google-chrome with 64 bit .

If you want to know more about google-chrome-stable visit this link :

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/google-chrome-stable